# LinearLayout with TextEdit and EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

When I run the following code from my activity_main.xml file, I get this output:

Width

Height

Area

Perimeter

There is no area on the screen to input any values for the EditText fields.  I have created the ids in my xml using the line: android:id="@+id/id_value".  In Eclipse, I also did Project -> Clean and restarted the emulator.  If anyone could point me in the right direction of what might be going on, that would be great.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jtryon.rectanglecalc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/width_string"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/width_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />        

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >  

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/height_string"
    android:textSize="12sp" /> 

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/height_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />     

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:text="@string/area_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area_string"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="@string/area_string" />    

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/perim_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/perim_string"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/perim_string" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your layout_width on the TextView and EditText as match_parent inside of a horizontal LinearLayout.

Set the layout_weight of the TextView and EditText as 1 (probably the better option as they will both take up 50% of the width) or change the width of both to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help you..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jtryon.rectanglecalc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/width_string"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/width_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/height_string"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/height_edit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text="@string/area_string" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area_string"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/area_string" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/perim_string" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/perim_string"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/perim_string" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I fixed the problem by setting the android:layout_width property to wrap_content for the TextView objects.  I was using match_parent and so what was happening is that the text where the result is displayed for area/perim were covered up by the other TextView.